# How can I access hadoop via the hdfs protocol from java?

Tags: ssh, hadoop, hdfs

I found a way to connect to hadoop via `hftp`, and it works fine, (read only) :

```
uri = "hftp://172.16.xxx.xxx:50070/";

System.out.println( "uri: " + uri );           
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get( URI.create( uri ), conf );
fs.printStatistics();
```

However, I want to read/write as well as copy files, that is, I want to connect over hdfs .  How can I enable hdfs connections so that i can edit the actual , remote filesystem  ?

I tried to change the protocol above from `hftp` -> `hdfs`, but I got the following exception ...

(forgive my poor knowledge of url protocols and hadoop , I assume this is a somewhat strange question im asking, but any help would really be appreciated !)

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Call to /172.16.112.131:50070 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1139)     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:226)   at $Proxy0.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:398)     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:384)     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:111)   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:213)  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:180)  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1514)   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:1548)  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1530)  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:228)     at sb.HadoopRemote.main(HadoopRemote.java:24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding hadoop : You need to make sure the `core-site.xml` namenode entry is serving to `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` (localhost) in your hadoop configuration.  Importantly, clouderas `vm distro` defaults to `localhost` for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `core-site.xml` and the `hdfs-site.xml` of the hadoop you want to hit to `conf`, something like this:

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * @author karan
 *
 */
public class HadoopPushTester {

    @Test
    public void run() throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        conf.addResource(new Path("src/test/resources/HadoopConfs/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("src/test/resources/HadoopConfs/hdfs-site.xml"));

        String dirName = "hdfs://hosthdfs:port/user/testJava";

        // Values of hosthdfs:port can be found in the core-site.xml  in the fs.default.name
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);


        Path path = new Path(dirName);
        if (fileSystem.exists(path)) {
            System.out.println("Dir " + dirName + " already exists");
            return;
        }

        // Create directories
        fileSystem.mkdirs(path);

        fileSystem.close();
    }
}
```